# Including multiple of the same YAML launch files in a Python launch file

Tags: launch-file, ros2-launch

I would like to launch multiple of the same yaml launch files from a Python launch file with slightly different parameters for each one.

Reading the official ROS2 documentations and also looking at the `ros2/launch` codebase, I am able to import a single yaml launch file with the following syntax.

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch_yaml.launch_description_sources import YAMLLaunchDescriptionSource


def generate_launch_description():
    launch_include = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        YAMLLaunchDescriptionSource(
            yaml_launch_file_path,
            launch_arguments={
                    "some_parameter": "some_value"
            },
        )
    )

    return LaunchDescription([launch_include])
```

Of course, I could create multiple launch_include variables, but I would like to do this by having a list of these "IncludeLaunchDescripton" objects and unpack this list in `LaunchDescription`:

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch_yaml.launch_description_sources import YAMLLaunchDescriptionSource


def generate_launch_description():
    launch_includes = []
    
    for i in range(5):
        launch_includes.extend(
            IncludeLaunchDescription(
                YAMLLaunchDescriptionSource(
                    yaml_launch_file_path,
                    launch_arguments={
                            "some_parameter": f"{i}"
                    },
                )
            )
        )

    return LaunchDescription([*launch_includes])
```

However, I get an error as the following:

```
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): Caught exception when trying to load file of format [py]: 'IncludeLaunchDescription' object is not iterable
```

What would be the correct way for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Silly me... Should be using `launch_includes.append(IncludeLaunchDescription())`, not extend !